# Facebook Newsfeed Popup in Laravel 4 with Javascript (or otherwise)

Tags: jquery, facebook, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to have the newsfeed dialog pop up for a user that clicks on a button (to post something on their Facebook wall).  I already have a logged in Facebook user that has been authenticated (using the laravel-oauth2 package and the built in Auth system with Laravel 4).  However, when I run the following script, nothing happens:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID_HERE',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            oauth      : true
            xfbml      : true  
    });

    $( '.opener' ).click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://example.com',
            name: 'NEWSFEED',
            caption: 'This is a test',
            description: {{$artist->stage_name}}

            });

      });
};

</script>
```

button:

```
<a class="add-list-button opener" style="color: white; font:14px / 14px 'DINMedium','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Play my city</a>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens.  Do you see anything wrong with what I have here?  If there is a better solution using my already authenticated user, let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Open up your console and let us know what JS errors your receive. Usually FB spits out an error into console that's helpful, esp when creating FB.ui elements.

Comment: There are no errors in the console related to the FB code;  there was an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" relating to the xfbml line, but I removed that, and it still isn't working.

Comment: Cool - next check the network tab to see outgoing requests and their response - likely is where the error message is (part of the response). You'll need to scroll to the bottom of the list of requests to see the latest one pop up.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything related to FB in the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you do change the listener from a `$('.opener')` function to a `$.on()` function?

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID_HERE',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            oauth      : true
            xfbml      : true  
    });

    // See changes below
    $(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://example.com',
            name: 'NEWSFEED',
            caption: 'This is a test',
            description: {{$artist->stage_name}}

            });

      });
};

</script>
```

Comment: Still nothing happens.  The feed doesn't come up.

Comment: Does the FB.init create any network traffic at all? Would you be able to create a JsFiddle and link to it in your answer?

Comment: What is the purpose of the double curly braces? I'm getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` on the line with the description, i.e. `description: 'Tell your friends you want ' + {{$artist->stage_name}} + ' to play your city!'`

Comment: In Laravel 4, that operates as an <?php echo variable ?>

Comment: Okay. I created a test page on my server with a different App ID, and can confirm that it works. Check out the source code of [my test page](http://joshuasmock.com/facebook_test.html).

Comment: AWESOME!  That piece of code you had before the window sync took care of it.  Thank you sir.  Well earned bounty.

Comment: You mean the Javascript that includes the Facebook library? This answer should be amended if it's to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You missed quotes on description, since {{ $artist->stage_name }} outputs string.

After adding single/double quotes, your code should work (if click event is binded right way, of course)

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID_HERE',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            oauth      : true
            xfbml      : true  
    });

    // See changes below
    $(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://example.com',
            name: 'NEWSFEED',
            caption: 'This is a test',
            description: '{{$artist->stage_name}}'

            });

      });
};

</script>
```